Why is (remote) Jupyter busy during ML training, but not actually doing anything?
I am training an ML model with PyTorch on my own dedicated remote server, using Jupyter as my IDE.
Around 120 epochs (about 2 hours into training), the Jupyter cell stops updating the output, but the status bar still says busy as the kernel status, and the SSH connection is still active.
I thought that maybe training was continuing, but the output cell stopped updating because it contains too much output. To check this hypothesis, I left Jupyter running for about 7 hours last night. When I woke up, it had stopped updating the output cell at 123 epochs, and when I killed the execution and printed out the current number of epochs, it had only reached 126 epochs.
Any idea what could be causing this?

Tip: Jupyter developed out of the IPython notebook, where the 'I' stands for 'Interactive'.  It excels at things where you are running interactively, not long running processes. For long running processes you are better off using Python in your console/terminal directly, or calling a script with Python from the command line, in the traditional way of running Python code. Then combine with doing that use screen or tmux (or a modern alternative) to detach and reattach later to see the result. Also, see here.

Thanks for the suggestion. I prefer using Jupyter until I get my code debugged and the hyperparameter selection down: I'm doing energy-based modeling, so viewing the evolution of samples over many epochs to ensure that they look reasonable and are making progress is important for both of these reasons. I plan to run it as a script, for several days, once I am confident I have a good set of hyperparameters.

Could you provide a minimal reproducible example of the code you're running?
On top of that I would suggest to:

Run the training from a python script instead of a jupyter notebook. Write the output to a file instead of printing to the standard output and check if the issue persist
Run the training on a reduced version of the dataset: in this way you should be able to reach the same amount of epochs in less time. If the problem persists after the same time interval, the problem may be related to the number of epochs, otherwise it may be related to the running time.
Run the training on a different machine/on your laptop, to check if the problem is related to the remote machine you're running on. (If it's too computationally heavy for your laptop, you might use a reduced version of the dataset here as well)

